# python socketio - open packet not returned by the server

Tags: node.js, django, socket.io

I am trying to connect to a socket server (node.js) say http://localhost:4300. On the server side it has been successfully connected,

on my server's log

> client connected {client_id}

but on my client side (python-socketio client) it returns exceptions

> OPEN Packet not returned by the server

Could anyone please help me explain why I got this exceptions? I have been doing what the docs said.

Answer (score 9):

This might indicate that the server and client versions are not compatible.
What worked for me was pinning the package versions of python-engineio and python-socketio:

```
pip install python-engineio==3.14.2 python-socketio==4.6.0
```

(source: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/586 )

Regarding version compatiblity see also https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

client installed python-engineio-4.0.1 python-socketio-5.1.0
my code in client is

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client(logger=True, engineio_logger=True)


@sio.event
def connect():
    print('connection established')


@sio.event
def my_message(data):
    print('message received with ', data)
    sio.emit('my response', {'response': 'my response'})


@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print('disconnected from server')


sio.connect(url='https://socket-io.insertmendoza.com.ar')
sio.wait()
```

my code in server is

```
import fs from 'fs'
import express from 'express'
import https from 'https'
import socket from 'socket.io'
import moment from 'moment'
import cors from 'cors'
import axios from 'axios'

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

const server = https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('/home/insert/Production/cdn/letsencrypt/live/npm-1/privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/home/insert/Production/cdn/letsencrypt/live/npm-1/fullchain.pem'),
}, app)

const users = {};

const io = socket(server)

server.listen(443, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:443', moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'))
})

"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "socket.io": "3.1.2"
  },
```

terminal debug

```
Attempting polling connection to https://socket-io.insertmendoza.com.ar/socket.io/?transport=polling&EIO=4
Polling connection accepted with {'sid': 'SZHctF0Fa0SMfEiiAAAA', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 5000}
Engine.IO connection established
Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
Attempting WebSocket upgrade to wss://socket-io.insertmendoza.com.ar/socket.io/?transport=websocket&EIO=4
WebSocket upgrade was successful
Received packet MESSAGE data 0{"sid":"8qEnsIwaom7Tgl8ZAAAB"}
Namespace / is connected
connection established
Received packet MESSAGE data 2["yourID","8qEnsIwaom7Tgl8ZAAAB"]
Received event "yourID" [/]
Received packet MESSAGE data 2["allUsers",{"8qEnsIwaom7Tgl8ZAAAB":"8qEnsIwaom7Tgl8ZAAAB"}]
Received event "allUsers" [/]
Received packet PING data 
Sending packet PONG data 
Received packet PING data 
Sending packet PONG data 
Received packet PING data 
Sending packet PONG data
```

in server is

```
listening on *:443 26/03/2021 17:56:00
connection Id: 8qEnsIwaom7Tgl8ZAAAB Auth: undefined IP: ::ffff:192.168.88.252 26/03/2021 18:02:20
```